# bokeh heatmap discrepancy

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm learning Bokeh and ran the following example:

```
from bokeh.charts import HeatMap, output_file, show

import pandas as pd

    output_file('heatmap.html')

df = pd.DataFrame(
        dict(
            apples=[4, 5, 8],
            bananas=[1, 2, 4],
            pears=[6, 5, 4],
        ),
        index=['2012', '2013', '2014']
    )

p = HeatMap(df, title='Fruits')

show(p)
```

[image]

It does not match what it is supposed to be:

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.9.3/docs/user_guide/charts.html#heatmap

Anybody have any ideas to fix the color? Thanks!

Comment: `0.9.3` is a fairly old version of Bokeh, and the Charts API and has only recently stabilized. Are you *actually* using version `0.9.3`? If not, you should always refer to the documentation specifically for the version you are *actually using*. For reference, the latest docs are always at http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Also for reference, here is an up to date example for the latest release `0.11.1` from the project repository: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/0.11.1/examples/charts/file/heatmap.py

Comment: Thanks. I am using 0.11.1, the latest version. In the example, it seem the colors are set by palette. Is there a way to customize palettes? Basically, I would like to have red for 0s and green for 1s. None of the preset palettes works this way. Thanks.

Comment: palettes are just lists of colors: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/0.11.1/bokeh/palettes.py you can definitely pass in whatever list of colors you like, you are not limited to the built in ones

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Is there a way to specify the which value gets which color? For example, If I have 10 values, 1-10. How to specify each values' color code? Thanks!

Comment: At the moment, you can't specify explicit bin/color mappings to a chart. It may be a feature to be discussed. I suggest to open an issue (to https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) with the details of your use case so we can drive an appropriate discussion and address it better.
At the moment the not so great thing you can do with Charts interface is to pass a palette that is sized in a way you can predict the  color/bin matches (the paletter order is maintained)
As an alternative you can create your heatmap with the bokeh plotting interface and do your own bins/color matches (with more code)

Comment: Thanks Fabio Pliger! If I use the bokeh plotting interface to do my own bins, is there an example? I searched but nothing come close to me... You mind give me some ideas? Even very rough would help! Thanks a lot.